# Searching a string using grep

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I want to search a line of code, which i want to debug, in my current directory. I donot the name of the file which contains the string. I tried this

```
grep -F "<div id="serv">"
```

But it doesn't return any result and the cursor just keeps blinking in terminal. The directory has many files so maybe its taking a lot of time for it to execute. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the quotes and because you did not specify where it has to look for. Try this:

```
grep -F '<div id="serv">' *
```

or

```
grep -F '<div id="serv">' /your/dir/*
```

Comment: * means it will search all the files in the current directory and subdirectories?

Comment: `*` means in this directory. If you want to search in subdirectories, add `-r` to grep: `grep -rF ...`

Comment: It worked but it is giving the result `test/theme.php:echo '<div id="serv">' . "\n";`. But there is no test folder in my directory. So what does that mean?

Comment: Mmmm it is difficult to say. To know which is the exact file matching, write the full path in grep: `grep -F .... /your/dir/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/<div id="serv">/ {print NR,$0,"->",FILENAME}' *
```

This will search all files for `<div id="serv">`
If found, print line number, line and filename,